# Hide DataPoint Label if Zero in Chart in RDLC Report

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I want to hide the datapoint label if the value of my datapoint is zero. I am trying the following field expression in visibility of series label property. It does not appear results as expected.

```css
=IIf(Sum(Fields!RH_Col.Value, "DataSet2") = 0, false, true)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the **Scope** of your statement... You are checking the whole **DataSet**, but you should be checking the **Category Group** only, something like:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!RH_Col.Value, "Chart1_CategoryGroup1") = 0, false, true)
```

These names are typically auto-generated, so check the Category Group properties to get yours.